# @OneToMany Persistence Set is not retrieved for some entities

Tags: java, spring-batch, jpa

I've been searching for a while on a solution to my issue, and am currently stuck.

I have a spring-batch application that retrieves entities from my database to delete them.
The batch works just fine on 3 out of 4 environments (local machine, test server, etc).

Testing the database on the K.O. server with the application on my machine does the same thing. (And the code already is the same on all 4 instances).

Here's what happens:

My first object

```
@Table(name = "TABLE_1")
public class Object1 {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="object1")
    private Set<Object2> myObj2 = new HashSet<Object2> ();
}
```

My second object

```
@Table(name = "TABLE_2")
public class Object2 {
    ...
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @Index(name = "FK_TABLE_1")
    @JoinColumn(name = "TABLE_1_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Object1 obj1;
}
```

So now, logically, my batch will get `Object1` (to be exact I will have a `ParentObject` that will contain multiple `Object1` entities) with the list of `Object2` so that I can delete them (using `entity.remove()`, nothing custom).

However this does not entirely work on one server in particular, on one entity in particular (maybe there are others but the batch throws an exception at this level).

I've checked the database constraints, data, and everything I could check, and the database is virtually identical, so there should be no reason that this entity/the lines in the tables do not get deleted.

Spring-batch chunk sizes are the same on every server/machine that executes the batch, the same version of Java is surely used (the `pom.xml` files are the same).

Any help and/or ideas are very welcomed.
Thank you.

**Edit 1 : Forgot the exception :**

**USER.FK_FROM_TABLE_2 : a foreign key that says : table_1 (the id) must be referenced in table_2**

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not delete: [Object1#14382]; SQL [delete from table_1 where id=? and version=?]; constraint [null]; 
    nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not delete: [Object1#14382]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:643)
..
    at fr.covea.troisma.soja.batch.BatchService.launchJob(BatchService.java:69)
    at fr.mma.soecm.batchpurgedonnees.Main.main(Main.java:89)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not delete: [Object1#14382]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
..
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:76)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:512)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02292: constraint violation (USER.FK_FROM_TABLE_2)  - enregistrement fils existant

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
..
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2711)
    ... 34 more
14:42:48,480 ERROR [] [AbstractStep] - Encountered an error saving batch meta data. This job is now in an unknown state and should not be restarted.
org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException: Attempt to update step execution id=1 with wrong version (1), where current version is 2
..
    at fr.mma.soecm.batchpurgedonnees.Main.main(Main.java:89)
14:42:48,481 ERROR [] [Main] - Batch does not complete successfuly: status=UNKNOWN
```

Comment: can you share exception?

Comment: yeah..forgot. hope you get the idea.

Comment: Don't you need to specify cascade options to have the associated collection removed first, thus avoiding the FK violation? http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/delete

Comment: I believe this is already the case, since it's working for 95% of the entities processed. Furthermore The entity code is automatically generated (spring-roo) so normally all is setup here. 
Does that make sense ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this issue by deleting the 'false data' from the database.

Whilst this is not the ideal solution, a colleague has probably solved the issue, giving me a bit of 'persistence theory'.

His idea is that the records of `Object2` that where not recovered, where in fact corrupt by another user's manual input.

Since there is not other sign that the database has been modified by our code, and seeing as how whe acces the database through a persistence API, the internal database registry must be out of sync with what is actually in the database.

To be more clearer : if the (for example) "VERSION" column in the registry is/was set to "2", put the database contains "0", then the Java objects will not be recovered. 
It is furthermore impossible for us/me to say what has been modified, in terms of 'persistence sensitive fields', so we can only conclude that this was a human error.

I hope this helps someone else as well.